# How to find the ip address of the tor entry/guard node I am currently connected to?

Tags: ip-address, guard-node

I have heard Tor blocks traffic analysis so it is not possible to get the middle relay ip address. How do I find the ip address of the entry relay? Does traceroute help in doing that? I also use tor on android. I use orbot to connect to Tor on android. So I like to know a solution on android too.

Answer (score 0):

A classic `traceroute` utility will end it's trace on Tor+transPort node, because tor is protecting you by diverting and randomising the L3+4 routes. But you have the full analog of the `traceroute` tool - either in Tor browser it's already built-in as a plugin(TorButton, if I'm correct) and froma command-line you can use [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/) to query the Tor instance about all the details, including the entry info.

Answer (score 0):

All IP addresses of nodes can be seen (entry, middle and exit), in the latest version of the TBB (8.0), you have to click on the locker icon to display them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TOR browser, there is an icon near the address bar, if you click on it, a window will be appeared displaying three IPs (Entry Guard, Middle Relay, Exit Node).

If you've connected to a hidden service, there are three more onion routers in order to hide the hidden service's real IP address.

And finally If you're using the former versions of TOR browser, you can see these information by clicking the TorButton (Onion like button before address bar). Hope it helps.

I've took a screenshot of the newer version of TOR browser, displaying the information. In this example I've connected to this hidden service: http://uutctfysirwosxjx.onion/

[image: The Onion Routers]