# Tor for Android has connected but "Proxy Server refuse connection"

Tags: proxy, android

I have been using Tor browser on my computer and it's been working fine on WiFi. I decided to download the latest Tor browser for Android and connected it with a successful connection but when I want to browse, I get a "PROXY SERVER REFUSE CONNECTION" . I have uninstalled the app several times and installed again but I still get the same problem. I have searched online for solution but found non. I have seen some people ask this same question on other forum but get no replies. Please has anyone experience this before or know the solution? Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm that this is the browser that you are using? https://www.torproject.org/download/#android

Comment: Yes. I was got mine from Android playstore. I've download the app from the web link you sent above and it worked for a while then lost proxy connection again.

Comment: Тоже не могу зайти, прокси не соединяет. Помогите!

Comment: This is a test https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13783/how-to-find-the-ip-address-of-the-tor-entry-guard-node-i-am-currently-connected

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of the Russian state censorship. We're - my project community and I - are working on the fix, and will publish it soon. All you need now is to find an *unpublished* bridge for Tor: the proxy-related error message is actually an error message from a plugable transport that indicates that it can't reach the bridge - the bridge is banned or filtered. Prefer obfs4 bridges for now

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix that works for me. On my Galaxy S20, I went Settings > Connections > More connection settings > Private DNS. Mine was on OFF. Select AUTOMATIC and see if it establishes a connection. I do warn you though, Using in conjunction with a vpn (like proton, a generally fast vpn) I found it to be at leased twice as long load times, sometimes more.